# Find the property name in the parent class

Tags: c#, .net

```cs
public class Order
{
    ---
    public Address BillingAddress {get;set;}
    public Address ShippingAddress {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    ---
    public Order Parent {get; set;}
    [RequiredParentAttribute]
    public string City {get;set;}
    [RequiredParentAttribute]
    public string ZipCode {get;set;}
}
```

I have the model above ,I have an instance of object Address and I'm looking on a way to find the name in the parent class in my case it's **`Order`**

In case the instance of object is the `BillingAddress` I would like to have the name somehow using reflexion

All I have today is the instance of that object.

So my starting point is

```cs
Address myInstance = getInstanceFromSomething()
```

The solution must stay generic and not focused on this classes at all.

Comment: The same object might be referred to from several orders (potentially multiple times) or none. You could easily check if you had a set of *possible* orders, but there's nothing in .NET that says "look at every object in memory to see if it refers to this object".

Comment: @JonSkeet What if I have the parent and has access to it.

Comment: @HichamBouchilkhi Then you can just check `Parent.BillingAddress == this` or `Parent.ShippingAddress == this` (assuming you didn't overload `==` to do anything funny). Note that it could be both addresses.

Comment: And you can do that with reflection by iterating over the properties, fetching the property values, and checking whether the value is the reference you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the type of a property like this:

```
Type? propertyType = address.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Address.Parent))?.PropertyType;
```

Or, if you want to find all properties of a specific type:

```
var properties = address.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Order));
```